# Sprinkler Javascript index.html not showing animated gif/webm format

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple javascript project that uses the sprinkler.js as found on https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprinkler to put graphics to sprinkle. It works very well if you use typical image format such as png/jpeg, but I was wondering if there is a way to use .gif/.webm/or video format to show animation to sprinkle. So far no success trying to put gif replacement to my current png. Thank you very much in advance!

Here are my codes:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sprinkler@1.9.0/dist/sprinkler.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and script.js:

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
var s = sprinkler.create(c)
var audio = new Audio('test.mp3');

function sprinkle(message) {
    audio.play();

    var images = [
        'Test1.png',
        'Test2.png'
      ]
      var stop = s.start(images, {
        ddyMin: 200,
        ddyMax: 200
      })
      setTimeout(function(){
        stop();
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
      }, 6000)
}
```